# How get component instance from unnamed slots on Vue.js2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have next template:

```
<TableComponent>
    <TableColumn v-bind:field="'firstName'" v-bind:label="'First Name">
</TableColumn>
```

How i can get component instances of `TableColumn`?

On TableComponent I have next `mounted` method:

```
mounted () {
    const columnComponents = this.$slots.default
    .filter(column => column.componentInstance)
    .map(column => column.componentInstance)

    console.info(columnComponents)
},
```

But on console info I got empty array. How I can get `TableColumn` props?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

```
<TableComponent>
    <TableColumn ref="tableColumn" v-bind:field="'firstName'" v-bind:label="'First Name">
</TableColumn>
```

and then

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        const col = this.$refs.tableColumn;
    });
}
```

Comment: It returns `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe `TableColumn` not mounted?

Comment: If the child isn't mounted, you can use `.nextTick` Updating answer now

Comment: How I can mount child component? Without use `.nextTick`?